# Sharepoint OOB download web service

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I've a Mobile device client to Sharepoint 2010 site .
I want to implement resumable download on Mobile device through out of box sp webservices.

Is there any way it can be done using OOB web services or do i need to write a customised SP web service by implementing IHttpHandler interface as i know HTTP supports Accept-Range ,eTag header .

If it possible using OOB web service ,How it can be achieved ...

Thanks

Comment: Any reply on this ....please share your thoughts ...

Answer (score 0):

Resumable download is only possible if server supports HTTP Range Request. You may also try Disk Based Caching for the BLOB object of sharepoint.

Please refer to this post

[SharePoint 2010 / IIS 7.5 Byte-Range Request Responds With Entire File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571115/sharepoint-2010-iis-7-5-byte-range-request-responds-with-entire-file)

If you are able to do this please post it here also. I am also looking for a solution of this.